# Convert the following into rectangular/cartesian form: $r^2sin2\theta=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

**Question**

Convert the following into rectangular/cartesian form: $r^2sin2\theta=1$

I was wondering if you would need to convert $\sin2\theta$ into the double angle formula form or if i would need to divide by r on both sides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double angle formula:

$$1=r^2\sin2\theta=r^2(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)=2(r\sin\theta)(r\cos\theta)$$

Comment: how would i proceed from there?

Comment: @JohnRawls What are $x,y$ in polar form?